# Should reviews/ratings data be considered as repeated measures?

Tags: inference, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model, intraclass-correlation, rating

Suppose I have some ratings/review data for a type of product (say coffee). There are many different kinds of coffee and there are many different subjects reviewing coffee and also some covariates associated with each review.

For example, Coffee Brand A has 30 reviews by 30 different people, and Coffee Brand B has 45 reviews by 45 different people. It is possible that one of the reviewers reviewed both Coffee Brand A and Coffee Brand B.

Say that I'm interested in what covariates are predictive of the rating given in a review, and my interest is in inference, not strictly minimizing an accuracy metric. (Are darker roasts more popular than lighter roasts?)

How would I go about this? The data appears to me to have clustering (by the coffee brands) since everyone who tries coffee brand A will have some correlation in their response (they all tasted the same thing, so if they all said "earthy" in their response on the flavor tones, we shouldn't be surprised).

Not only that, there could be correlation across the coffee brands, because someone might've reviewed more than one brand.

I think for the purposes of inference, a multi-level model should be considered, with random effects. But the correct approach is not totally clear to me.